# Problems with passing data to php using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I have a html form that is supposed to submit data to a php file through jquery ajax. the code can be seen below.The problem I am having is that on clicking submit, the ajax seems not to be passing data to php as the console.log under the done() function returns a $data object showing that all fields are empty (i.e returning the error messages when the fields are empty). I am simply not getting where the problem is. When I submit the form without using ajax i.e disabling the entire $('form').submit (...) block, the success message returns true. the ajax blocks always returns false

```
<form id="sds_contact_form" class="sds_form" action="form_submit.php" method="post">
                    <!-- name -->
                    <div class="sds_input_group sds_half_field">
                        <label for="sds_sender_name">full name*</label>
                        <input id="sds_sender_name" name="sds_customer" type="text" placeholder="eg John smith" required />
                        <span id="sds_customername_error" class="sds_error_span"></span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- email address -->
                    <div class="sds_input_group sds_half_field">
                        <label for="sds_sender_email">email*</label>
                        <input id="sds_sender_email" name="sds_form_email" type="email" placeholder="eg j.smith@example.com" required />
                        <span id="sds_email_error" class="sds_error_span"></span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- subject -->
                    <div class="sds_input_group">
                        <label for="sds_email_subject">subject*</label>
                        <input id="sds_email_subject" name="sds_form_subject" type="text" placeholder="e.g need an app designed" required />
                        <span id="sds_subject_error" class="sds_error_span"></span>
                    </div>
                    <!--enquiry -->
                    <div class="sds_input_group">
                        <label for="sds_sender_enquiry">enquiry*</label>
                        <span id="sds_enquiry_error" class="sds_error_span"></span>
                        <textarea id="sds_sender_enquiry" name="sds_form_enquiry" placeholder="enter details here" rows="15" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <!-- submit button -->
                    <button  name="sds_submit_enquiry" type="submit" class="sds_form_button sds_button">send</button>
                </form>
```

This is the jquery code

```
//form data submission
$('form').submit(function(event){
    var form_data = {
        'customer_name' : $('#sds_sender_name').val(),
        'customer_email' : $('#sds_sender_email').val(),
        'email_subject': $('#sds_email_subject').val(),
        'enquiry': $('#sds_sender_enquiry').val()
    };
    console.log(form_data);

    $.ajax({
        url :'form_submit.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:form_data,
        dataType:'json',

    }).done(function(data){
        console.log(data);

    }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        console.log("ERROR:" + xhr.responseText+" - "+thrownError);
    });
    event.preventDefault();


});
```

This is the PHP Code in form_submit.php

```
<?php

$data = array();
$errors = array();

//get form data
$customer_name = $_POST['sds_customer'];
$customer_email = $_POST['sds_form_email'];
$email_subject = $_POST['sds_form_subject'];
$enquiry = $_POST['sds_form_enquiry'];  

//validate name
if(empty($customer_name)){
    $errors['customer_name'] = 'name is required';
}

//validate email
if(empty($customer_email)){
    $errors['customer_email'] = 'email is required';
}else{
    if(!filter_var($customer_email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $errors['customer_email'] = 'email provided is invalid';
    }
    $customer_email = filter_var($customer_email,FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
}

//validate form subject
if(empty($email_subject)){
    $errors['email_subject'] = 'subject is required';
}else{
    $email_subject = filter_var($email_subject,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}

//validate form comments
if(empty($enquiry)){
    $errors['enquiry'] = 'please enter your enquiry';
}else{
    $enquiry = filter_var($enquiry,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}



if(!empty($errors)){
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors'] = $errors;
}else{
    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] = "Your email has been sucessfully sent. Thank you for your enquiry. Exepect a response soon!";

    //further data processing here....


}
echo json_encode($data);
```

?>

Comment: In done section you should use JSON.parse(data); as you are passing json decode from php

Comment: @Jigar7521 No, he shouldn't. If the dataType of AJAX is defined as JSON, JSON.parse isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is about parameters names At jquery the parameter is defined as:

```
var form_data = {
    'customer_name' : $('#sds_sender_name').val(),
    'customer_email' : $('#sds_sender_email').val(),
    'email_subject': $('#sds_email_subject').val(),
    'enquiry': $('#sds_sender_enquiry').val()
};
```

At PHP, you are using a sds prefix (as write in the form):

```
//get form data
$customer_name = $_POST['sds_customer'];
$customer_email = $_POST['sds_form_email'];
$email_subject = $_POST['sds_form_subject'];
$enquiry = $_POST['sds_form_enquiry'];
```

Your parameters should match with AJAX, not with form (as below).

```
$customer_name = $_POST['customer_name'];
$customer_email = $_POST['customer_email'];
$email_subject = $_POST['email_subject'];
$enquiry = $_POST['enquiry'];
```

Or just use serialized on form:

```
$.ajax(
    data: $("#sds_contact_form").serialize(),
    /*** others parameters ***/
```

Comment: Yeeeeessssss! Switched the code  and its working now! The only concern I have is when someone has javascript turned off, it will not work. how can I code it to accommodate both situations in the php file?

Comment: To answer myself, the second solution (serializing the form) caters for both situations i.e. I don't have make the parameters match with AJAX.

Comment: If you serialize the form, it'll came with the parameters name from your HTML form. So, your PHP should match with form names (as you did before)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#sds_contact_form").serialize() // returns all the data in your form

$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'form_submit.php',
     data: $("#sds_contact_form").serialize(),
     dataType:'json',
     success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
     }
});
```

In you php file Unserialize your data

```
unserialize($data);
```

Comment: Thanks. your answer  complements @Gabriel Heming answer and helped me see how to cater for situations when both javascript is on and off