# How to receive jquery ajax data in a php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to create a form for submitting resume.

I need the candidate name, email , resume cover and the resume(file).

```
var candidateName = $('#candidateName').val();
var candidateEmail = $('#candidateEmail').val();
var candidateMessage = $('#candidateMessage').val();
var file_data = $('#candidateResume').prop('files')[0];


var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('file', file_data);
form_data.append('name', candidateName);
form_data.append('id', candidateEmail);
form_data.append('msg', candidateMessage);
console.log(form_data);

$.ajax({
    url: "cvForm.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {candata: form_data},
    success : function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

nothing is being returned in my cvForm.php file when I

```
var_dump($_POST) or
var_dump($_FILES)
```

when I

```
var_dump($_POST['candata']) - it says undefined index
```

The HTML

```
<form id="cvSubmit" class="mui-form">
                <div>
                    <span class="form-success-msg" id="cv-form-success-msg">
                        Thanks for reaching out to us. We will get back to you shortly.
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label">
                            <input type="text" id="candidateName" class="mui--is-empty mui--is-untouched mui--is-pristine">
                            <label>Name<span class="red-text">*</span></label>
                            <span class="error" id="cv-name-error">Please enter your name</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label">
                            <input type="email" id="candidateEmail" class="mui--is-empty mui--is-untouched mui--is-pristine">
                            <label>Email<span class="red-text">*</span></label>
                            <span class="error" id="cv-email-error">Oops!! Looks like its an incorrect email id. Try again</span>
                        </div>


                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 file-attachment-wrapper">
                                <input class="file-addach" type="file" id="candidateResume">
                                <span>We accept .DOCX,.Doc,pdf,.Txt upto 2 MB.</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6">

                        <div class="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label">
                            <label>Message<span class="red-text">*</span></label><br><br>

                            <textarea id="candidateMessage" rows="5" class="mui--is-empty mui--is-untouched mui--is-pristine"></textarea>
                            <span class="error" id="cv-message-error">That's not very clear...could you rephrase</span>
                        </div>

                        <button type="button" class="mui-btn mui-btn--raised red-btn" onclick="cvSubmit()"> SEND </button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </form>
```

Please help. I see this is a common question but none of the solution seems to work for me. Some code refreshes the page, which I don't want to happen.

Comment: you should (probably) post the HTML for this.

Comment: Always use `F12` dev-console in the browser while developing, mostly console and network tab.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with passing data to php using jquery ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504426/problems-with-passing-data-to-php-using-jquery-ajax)

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: are you paying attention to comments up here? I/we shouldn't have to post an answer in order to get your attention. I myself specifically posted a comment for you to post the HTML for this, and that was almost 10 mins. ago. Your question stands to get closed with [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”, “Notice: Undefined index”, and “Notice: Undefined offset”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4261133/1415724) based on the error message you posted and the one that you shown in one of the answers' comment area. We/I am trying our best to help but you seem to be sticking to one answer instead.

Comment: sorry.wil post now

Comment: @StacyJ Thanks. Where is the `cvSubmit()` method? Also handling files requires a valid enctype. This Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/18428935/1415724 shows an example and another http://stackoverflow.com/q/14495296/1415724 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/28121129/1415724. Plus, you may need to "name" your inputs.

Comment: @StacyJ and your `var form_data = new FormData();` should most likely read as `var form_data = new FormData($('#cvSubmit'));`

Comment: @StacyJ I revisted the question but saw no extra activity. You can ping me back if you want, I wish you well with this, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from your JS:

```
contentType: false,
```

That's telling jQuery to not set the content-type HTTP header.  That header tells PHP how to parse the POSTed body.

Also, formdata can be sent directly:

```
data: form_data,
```

Then, in PHP, you should find for example `$_POST['name']` available.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `form_data` in its normal form, instead of a property of another JSON object:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'cvForm.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: form_data,
    processData: false,
    success : function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Now inside of your PHP script, you will have access to `$_POST['name']`, `$_POST['id']` and `$_POST['msg']`. Similarly, `$_FILES['file']` is now available too.

Comment: I did var_dump($_POST['name']) - it gives me  Undefined index: name

Comment: Did you copy the excerpt exactly as posted above?

Comment: What happens if you print_r() the $_POST array?

Comment: I can see the data in an array..sharing the result below

Comment: Array
(
    [------WebKitFormBoundaryX29YrY3X1X9U8Efd
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "file"

undefined
------WebKitFormBoundaryX29YrY3X1X9U8Efd
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

John Doe
------WebKitFormBoundaryX29YrY3X1X9U8Efd
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id"

john.doe@gmail.com
------WebKitFormBoundaryX29YrY3X1X9U8Efd
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="msg"

Share your CV with us and we’ll be happy to have a look at it.
------WebKitFormBoundaryX29YrY3X1X9U8Efd--

)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It might help you.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="cvSubmit" class="mui-form">
            <div>
                <span class="form-success-msg" id="cv-form-success-msg">
                    Thanks for reaching out to us. We will get back to you shortly.
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label">
                        <input type="text" id="candidateName" class="mui--is-empty mui--is-untouched mui--is-pristine">
                        <label>Name<span class="red-text">*</span></label>
                        <span class="error" id="cv-name-error">Please enter your name</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label">
                        <input type="email" id="candidateEmail" class="mui--is-empty mui--is-untouched mui--is-pristine">
                        <label>Email<span class="red-text">*</span></label>
                        <span class="error" id="cv-email-error">Oops!! Looks like its an incorrect email id. Try again</span>
                    </div>


                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 file-attachment-wrapper">
                            <input class="file-addach" type="file" id="candidateResume">
                            <span>We accept .DOCX,.Doc,pdf,.Txt upto 2 MB.</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6">

                    <div class="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label">
                        <label>Message<span class="red-text">*</span></label><br><br>

                        <textarea id="candidateMessage" rows="5" class="mui--is-empty mui--is-untouched mui--is-pristine"></textarea>
                        <span class="error" id="cv-message-error">That's not very clear...could you rephrase</span>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="mui-btn mui-btn--raised red-btn"> SEND </button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </form>

        <script>

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#cvSubmit").submit(function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();


                    var candidateName = $('#candidateName').val();
                    var candidateEmail = $('#candidateEmail').val();
                    var candidateMessage = $('#candidateMessage').val();
                    var file_data = $('#candidateResume').prop('files')[0];


                    var form_data = new FormData();
                    form_data.append('file', file_data);
                    form_data.append('name', candidateName);
                    form_data.append('id', candidateEmail);
                    form_data.append('msg', candidateMessage);
                    console.log(form_data);

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "cvForm.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: form_data,
                        success : function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                        },
                       contentType: false,
                       processData: false
                    });

                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

1. After this code, I was able to see the data in console
2. Changes the submit button to type 'submit' and handled the event handler for form submit and e.preventDefault() prevents from page refresh.

Hope it helps!